# Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'SHA1'

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Trying to get an edit page to work and im getting this error Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'SHA1'. The error is only on the SHA1. everything else works fine other then this error. Any helped is greatly appreciated. I don't want the password showing or the encryption that is to stay blank as it is an admin editing a staff members details and they dont need to know the password.

```
<?php
if(empty($_POST['submit'])) {


$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id = '$_GET[id]'";
//    $supplier_id  = $_GET['supplier_id'];
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
 }
else{

$update = "UPDATE user SET 
    title= '$_POST[inputtitle]',
    first_name ='$_POST[inputfirst_name]', 
    middle_name = '$_POST[inputmiddle_name]',
    last_name = '$_POST[inputlast_name]', 
    gender = '$_POST[inputgender]',
    email = '$_POST[inputemail]',
    pass = SHA1($_POST[inputSHA1pass]);
    car_make = '$_POST[inputcar_make]'
    car_model = '$_POST[inputcar_model]',
    prefer_car = '$_POST[inputprefer_car]',
    car_age = '$_POST[inputcar_age]',
    st_no = '$_POST[inputst_no]',
    st_name = '$_POST[inputst_name]',
    suburb = '$_POST[inputsuburb]',
    state = '$_POST[inputstate]',
    country = '$_POST[inputcountry]',
    postcode = '$_POST[inputpostcode]',


    WHERE user_id = $_POST[user_id]";

mysqli_query($dbc, $update) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));

echo "User has been modified!";
header("Location: view_user.php");
}
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].htmlspecialchars($_GET[‘id’]);     ?>" method="POST">

    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $supplier = $_GET['id']; ?>"   name="supplier_id">


            <p>Title:
                <input type="text" name="inputtitle" size="20" maxlength="30"
                       value="<?php echo $row["title"]; ?>"/>
            </p>

            <p>First Name:
                <input type="text" name="inputfirst_name" size="20" maxlength="30"
                       value="<?php echo $row["first_name"]; ?>"/></p>

            <p>Middle Name:
                <input type="text" name="inputmiddle_name" size="30" maxlength="100"
                       value="<?php echo $row["middle_name"]; ?>"/></p>

            <p>Last Name:
                <input type="text" name="inputlast_name" size="20" maxlength="30"
                       value="<?php echo $row["last_name"]; ?>"/></p>

            <p>Gender:
                <input type="text" name="inputgender" size="20" maxlength="30"
                       value="<?php echo $row["gender"]; ?>"/></p>

            <p>Email:
                <input type="text" name="inputemail" size="10" maxlength="5" 
                        value="<?php echo $row["email"]; ?>"/>
            </p><br>

            <p>Password:
                <input type="text" name="inputSHA1pass" size="30" maxlength="40"
                       value="<?php if (isset($_POST['pass'])) echo $_POST['pass']; ?>"/></p>

            <p>Car Make:
                <input type="text" name="inputcar_make" size="20" maxlength="30"
                       value="<?php echo $row["car_make"]; ?>"/></p>

            <p>Car Model:
                <input type="text" name="inputcar_model" size="20" maxlength="30"
                       value="<?php echo $row["car_model"]; ?>"/></p>

            <p>Prefered Car:
                <input type="text" name="inputprefer_car" size="20" maxlength="30"
                       value="<?php echo $row["prefer_car"]; ?>"/></p>

            <p>Car Age:
                <input type="text" name="inputcar_age" size="20" maxlength="30"
                       value="<?php echo $row["car_age"]; ?>"/></p>

            <p>Street Number:
                <input type="text" name="inputst_no" size="20" maxlength="30"
                       value="<?php echo $row["st_no"]; ?>"/></p>

            <p>Street Name:
                <input type="text" name="inputst_name" size="20" maxlength="30"
                       value="<?php echo $row["st_name"]; ?>"/></p>

            <p>Suburb:
                <input type="text" name="inputsuburb" size="20" maxlength="30"
                       value="<?php echo $row["suburb"]; ?>"/></p>

            <p>State:
                <input type="text" name="inputstate" size="20" maxlength="30"
                       value="<?php echo $row["state"]; ?>"/></p>

            <p>Country:
                <input type="text" name="inputcountry" size="20"    maxlength="30"
                       value="<?php echo $row["country"]; ?>"/></p>

            <p>Postcode:
                <input type="text" name="inputpostcode" size="20" maxlength="30"
                       value="<?php echo $row["postcode"]; ?>"/></p>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/></p>
        </form>
    <?php
            mysqli_close($dbc);
 ?>
<br>
 <br>
</div>
<br>
<?php
include ('../includes/footer.php');
?>
```

Comment: Why don't hash via PHP function instead of mysql? http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. Check that `$_POST['inputSHA1pass']` is not empty
2. Enclose `$_POST[inputSHA1pass]` in quote marks and curly braces: `SHA1('{$_POST[inputSHA1pass]}')`. `SHA1()` expects a string and will error without one
3. Look into prepared statements. As this code stands, it is wide open to SQL injection attacks as none of your passed data is checked for validity
4. Change the semi-colon to a comma in the SHA1 line
5. Finally, once the `UPDATE` query has been built, capture it and try running it directly on the database server. It should give you a more meaningful error message and make debugging easier

Comment: thank you, I'm not fussed about sql injection at this stage. i know about it but this is just a site for school, teaching me how to do php as i am only learning. Just beginning really.

Comment: I fixed that error though and now i am stuck with:  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE user_id =' at line 21. The form is populated with the staff members details, and the update query is fully populated when i echoed it. the only thing empy and erroring is the WHERE clause

Comment: @JarrydPaton - no prob. Look at using PDO as (and this is a purely personal opinion), prepared statements are a bit easier to understand. There are some short comings (like no built in function to retrieve the last inserted ID) but there's ways and means to get around it. Also, it abstracts the database connection somewhat so makes migration to another database system (Postgres, Oracle etc) a little bit easier. Good luck

Comment: Is the user_id field in the database a string or number? Related to that, is `$_POST['user_id']` a string or number? If the database is expecting a string, it needs to be enclosed in single quote marks. Also, you have a comma just before `WHERE user_id=`

Comment: it should be a string, its grabbing details off the page before this one. Which is a view staff page so you can see all the staff details then click the edit button next to their details and edit it

Comment: OK. As it's a string you need to put single quotes around the `$_POST['user_id']` bit in the `WHERE` clause.  Also, I noticed there was a comma after `postcode = '$_POST[inputpostcode]'` so remove that too (MySQL is expecting another field that it has to retrieve but is throwing an error as the `WHERE` clause appears)

Comment: is there anything in there that you can see that would stop it from sending updated data to the database? as ive just fixed the 2 things you mentioned, now no errors its just not updating anything

Comment: If you run the generated `$update` query on the database directly, it should show the numbers of rows updated. As there is only one criteria the user id), if 0 rows are updated, it would mean that the user ID doesn't exist in the table. Run a quick query along to check for its presence: `select * from user where user_id='asd'` )replace asd with the user you're trying to update)